# Changing one class to another

Tags: jquery, class, variables, concatenation

I'm about a week and a half into learning jquery but at about 10 hours a day I think I am getting a handle on some things, with help from other posts on here. I am very close to what I want to do. I want to swap the class g1 for p1, but I have to do this for 16 classes. I am considering doing something like this function to remove the number automatically for whichever p number is clicked.

```
    $(function imageswap() {
    $("[class^=g]").click(function () {
    var num = this.class.slice(1);
    var elem = ('.' + 'p' + num);
    });
    });
```

Then I would call use $('+elem+) to make use of this. Am I offtrack here or over complicating this?

In addition, how would I make use of this? I initially thought I would use it just as a standard click listener but it doesn't seem to be working. Something like this. Apologies if its a bit amateurish.

```
$(document).ready ( function(){
$("[class^=g]").click(function () {
    var num = this.class.slice(1);
    var elem = ('.' + 'p' + num);
$('.portalimg').transition({
    display:"none",
});
$(elem).transition({
    display:"block",
    opacity:"0",
    transform: "translateY(-400px) scale(.1,.1)",
    '-webkit-transform': "translateY(-400px) scale(.1,.1)",
    '-o-transform': "translateY(-400px) scale(.1,.1)",
    '-moz-transform': "translateY(-400px) scale(.1,.1)",
},1000);
$(elem).transition({
    '-webkit-transform': "translateY(0) scale(1,1)",
    '-moz-transform': "translateY(0) scale(1,1)",
    '-o-transform': "translateY(0) scale(1,1)",
    transform: "translateY(0) scale(1,1)",
    "border-radius": "0",
    opacity: "1"},2000);
});
});
```

Comment: it sounds like you may be going about your initial problem in the wrong way - things like 'I need to change 16 of them' usually means that you need to approach your problem in a different way

Comment: Well in this case I am swapping out the appropriate image in addition to executing an animation. If I can get this to work it will cut 16 sections of code out of my current document. I had it working without this selector as individual functions but as you can guess that is bulky, slow, and bad.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use like `$('+elem+)`, you can just use `elem` or `$(elem)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$each()` to overcome this kind problem.
[Jquery $each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)